# i would like to create a jar file using cmd

Tags: java, jar

After I type  (javac PosLajuMalaysia.java) in cmd, there was an error coming out like this:

**PosLajuMalaysia.java:163: error: cannot find symbol

```
                    new MainFrame().setVisible(true);                               
                        ^
```

symbol: class MainFrame

1 error**

Can i know what error is this and how would i fix it because when i run my program in ide(intellij), it does not display any syntax error
It appears to be at line 163 where i type

```
(line 16)           new MainFrame().setVisible(true);
                    setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the symbol 'MainFrame' is not found.

When you are using the javac command, you must specify all of the class that you want to compile.

> You can list more than one filename in the javac command. The following command compiles three files:
>
> javac TestProgram1.java TestProgram2.java TestProgram3.java

[source](https://www.dummies.com/programming/java/how-to-use-the-javac-command/)

Comment: do i need to list out all the classes as well? jar cfm PosLajuMalaysia.jar Manifest.txt example1.class example2.class example3.class

Comment: Where is the file: MainFrame.class located?  Is it on the classpath when the javac command is executed?

Comment: here is an exemple: `javac Main.java ui/MainFrame.java util/Utility.java`